# How I can print nicktitle from title using bibtex?

Tags: biblatex

I am dealing with bibliiography in LaTex. In biblography, we usually references to another books, their titles and so on. Somewhere we want, title entry as such and somewhere we want only shortform of title. As for author entry, we can produce shortname and fullauthor from same data written in .bib file. But I am unable to do this with title. How I can produce nicktitle from title. Is there problem with style that I am using. Here is my code.

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
 \RequirePackage{filecontents}
 \begin{filecontents*}{demo.bib}
  @book{is4562000,
   title={Indian Standard Plain and reinforced concrete--code of
    practice (IS 456 : 2000)},
   author={Cement and Concrete Sectional Committee, CED 2},
   journal={New Delhi: },
   year={2000},
   publisher={Bureau of Indian Standards},
  }

  @book{aci1981aci,
  title={ACI Standard Building Code Requirements for Reinforced
    Concrete (ACI 318-77)},
  author={{ACI Committee 318}},
  series={ACI standard 318-77},
  url={https://books.google.co.in/books?id=amEOfgtA-DYC},
  year=1981,
  publisher={American Concrete Institute},
 }   
 @STANDARD {aci31877,
 title        = {ACI Standard Building Code Requirements for
 Reinforced Concrete (ACI 318-77)},
 organization = {American Concrete Institute},
 institution  = {American Concrete Institute},
 author       = {{ACI Committee 318}},
 language     = {English},
 number       = {ACI standard 318-77},
 year         = 1981
 }   
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{demo.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citepublisher}
{\boolfalse{citetracker}%
\boolfalse{pagetracker}%
\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\printlist{publisher}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}

This is demo \cite{is4562000,aci1981aci,aci31877}
and the publisher of \texttt{aci1981aci} is     citepublisher{aci1981aci}
and of \texttt{is4562000} \citepublisher{is4562000}.
title : \citetitle{is4562000}\\


\textbf{Enteres from @Book}\\
\textbf{Author shortname:} \citeauthor*{is4562000}

\textbf{Author Fullname:} \citeauthor{is4562000}\\

\textbf{Entries from @standard}
\cite{aci31877}

\textbf{@Standard title}= \citetitle{aci31877}

\textbf{@Standard author}= \citeauthor{aci31877}

\textbf{@Standard shortauthor}= \citeauthor*{aci31877}


\textbf{@Standard year}= \citeyear{aci31877}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: [Crosspost to LaTeX community](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=27084)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reusing my answer from [LaTeX-community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=93321#p93321):

> You just need to define what the short author and short title are supposed to be, biblatex prints them by default.

```
%\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{demo.bib}
        @book{is4562000,
                title={Indian Standard Plain and reinforced concrete--code of
                practice (IS 456~:~2000)},
                shorttitle = {IS 456~:~2000},
                author={{Cement and Concrete Sectional Committee, CED 2}},
                shortauthor={{CED 2}},
                location={New Delhi},
                journal={New Delhi},% A book cannot be published
%               in a journal, that doesn't make any sense
                year={2000},
                publisher={Bureau of Indian Standards},
        }

        @book{aci1981aci,
                title={ACI Standard Building Code Requirements for Reinforced
                Concrete (ACI 318-77)},
                author={{ACI Committee 318}},
                series={ACI standard 318-77},
                url={https://books.google.co.in/books?id=amEOfgtA-DYC},
                year=1981,
                publisher={American Concrete Institute},
        }  
        @STANDARD {aci31877,
                title        = {ACI Standard Building Code Requirements for
                Reinforced Concrete (ACI 318-77)},
                shorttitle = {ACI 318-77},
                organization = {American Concrete Institute},
                institution  = {American Concrete Institute},
                author       = {{ACI Committee 318}},
                language     = {English},
                number       = {ACI standard 318-77},%that
%               doesn't seem to be a proper number either
                year         = 1981
        }  
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt}%JB: Tht doesn't make any sense with biblatex
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{demo.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citepublisher}
{\boolfalse{citetracker}%
\boolfalse{pagetracker}%
\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\printlist{publisher}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
Just citing the title: (\citetitle{is4562000})

Just citing the title: \citetitle{aci31877}

just citing the author: \citeauthor{is4562000}

just citing the author: \citeauthor{aci31877}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scanning the biblatex documentation (using texdoc in texlive2015) there is not any **shorttitle** field. Said that you may imaging alternative bib-entries with long or short titles and use these as you decide which one to use. The *problem* will be dealing with duplicates in your bib file.

Comment: Just me something, how I can produce subtitle from title.

Comment: subtitles are something different, since they are legitimate entries in bibtex. I had the impression you want abbreviated titles, and those you have make yourself.

Comment: `biblatex` supports `shorttitle`.

Comment: Thank you,  Johannes_B for giving me answer here also , you solved my problem.